# EventLogs using Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, event-log

Is there a way to access the event logs of a server (or the local machine for now) using Silverlight and C#?
The EventLog class is not available in Silverlight due to the System.Diagnostics namespace not being available for the Silverlight runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the log entries using a webservice (WCF for example) which can then be accessed from your SL app. Of course this works for server only. I don't know if it is possible for the client.

Comment: SL cant access local event log on client because of rights limitations.

Comment: Can you give me some reference as to how can I read the eventlogs using WCF or any other webservice? MSDN documentation only seems to talk about Event logging and tracing.

Comment: I never had to read it from an app, but on msdn it looks easy.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entries.aspx